# How do I add names before/after other player's names when they talk? (Prefixes/suffixes)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'll give you an example, we've got a guy named Jess. When he talks in chat it should show something like:

`"[somePrefix] <Jess> [someSuffix]: [Jess's message]"`

Comment: This question is not unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on singleplayer im not sure if there is a way and if there is idk how to do it

BUt if you are at singleplayer you need to have one of Three "PermissionsEX or Groupmanager OR Essentials" plugin you need one of those

if you was using PermissionsEX you have to first go to files

plugins --> PermissionsEX --> config.yml then allow Ops make set to true reload server then do the command /pex Group "if you want a a special rank to have this type name here if not just put default as its the normal rank for all players" prefix "then the name that you want"
EX: /pex Group default prefix &1[&6[&2Default&6]&1]

if you was using Essentials then you have to go to the files

Plugins --> Essentials  --> config.yml

then scroll down a bit untill you get to the "chat format"

then add the name that you want Before the {DISPLAYNAME}

as an example

format: '&7[{GROUP}]&r &1[&6[&2Default&&6]1] {DISPLAYNAME}&7:&r {MESSAGE}'

if you was using Groupmanager then you will do somthing similar for the PermissionsEX but the command will be different

instead of doin /pex Group default prefix &1[&6[&2Default&6]&1]

Do the command
/mangaddv default Prefix &1[&6[&2default&6]&1]

NOTE!! the Words "default" is the name of the player rank so all the players with this rank will get this prefix but if you had never used pex or groupmanager so all players will be at rank default by normal

Answer (score 1):

## Vanilla

This method requires [NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer).

1. Add a team to the scoreboard and join the team in-game.
2. Leave the game and open NBTExplorer. Navigate to: `saves/[world name]/data/scoreboard.dat [n entries]/data: n entries/Teams: n entries`, where `n` is (obviously) the number of entries.
3. Expand all sub-directories and locate the one with the `Name` value set to the name of the team you joined.
4. Modify the `Prefix` and `Suffix` values to your liking using color codes (e.g. modify `Prefix` to `§9Member §r` for a blue Member prefix) and save the edits.

---

## Modified servers

There are *many* ways to set user prefixes and suffixes with the help of external plugins in modified servers (CrafrBukkit, Spigot, Paper, etc.), some of which have been mentioned in alzeinfoaud’s answer already.

**GroupManager/PermissionsEx/similar plugins**

1. Create a group and join the group. (e.g. in PEx: `pex group member create` then `pex user Steve group add member`)
2. Modify the prefix and suffix to your liking. (e.g. in PEx: `pex group member prefix “&9Member &r” in-game, or modify` groups/member/options/prefix`value in`permissions.yml`)

**EssentialsChat**

1. Head to `config.yml` and scroll to `chat/group-formats` under the `EssentialsChat` section.
2. Add a new item to the list. Note that the name of the value must be identical to the group name in your permissions plugin. (e.g. there is a `member` group in your permissions configuration, so add `member: [chat format here]` to the list.)
3. Modify the prefix and suffix for each group to your liking.

**DeluxeChat**

1. Head to `config.yml` and scroll to the bottom.
2. Add a new section to the file. Modify the values.
3. Add the corresponding permission node `chatformat.[section name]` to the user group.

For detailed information on DeluxeChat configuration, head to its [plugin page](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/deluxechat.1277).

**iChat**

1. Head to `groups.yml`.
2. Add a new entry to the file. Modify the `format` value.
3. Add the corresponding permission mode `ichat.[group name]` to the user group.

For detailed information on iChat configuration, head to its [plugin page](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/ichat.43306).

**Note**

For all of the methods above, changes will only take place upon saving the file and reloading the plugin. Slightly off-topic, but using `/reload` is discouraged as it may break some plugins installed. It is better to use a plugin manager like [PlugMan](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/plugman) to reload plugins individually or initiate a server reboot.